# mp4 video uploaded from android not play on ios

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

We have an app that allows user to upload videos and images to server.
if i upload a mp4 video from android , it is not playing in ios devices.
this is my code. player status shows up readytoplay but it doesn't load up and no error comes up. vieo is playing fine with web and android.
 here is video url : https://justgolive.net/assets/uploads/newrecordings/20919/19777983355a28e15326df6.mp4

```
  NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_videoUrl];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamURL];

    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    playerLayer.frame =self.previewView.frame;
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    //CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/1.2);
    [self.previewView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    // [self.playerContainer setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];   //to avoid touch events when activity is on
    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[player currentItem]];
```

Comment: Have you called play method of player?

Comment: yes , iad adding [player play];

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with your url of Video and working with below code:

header file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *playerView;

@end
```

Implementation file like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://justgolive.net/assets/uploads/newrecordings/20919/19777983355a28e15326df6.mp4"];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    CALayer *superlayer = self.playerView.layer;
    self.player.volume = 20.0;

    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    [playerLayer setFrame:self.playerView.bounds];
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.layer.bounds;
    [superlayer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    [self.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self.player play];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: its not working. can you share project files? idid the same thing 100 times in the day and it did not come up to play

Comment: please find output after running app in my edited answer.Is it the video when url fetched in Android?

Comment: it is showing blank screen for me. this is really weired. i am checking it on simulator

Comment: have yo added app transport security in info.plist ?

Comment: Transport  security key is not required as url having https.And that key is required for http protocol.

Comment: Showing black screen because declare instance of AVPlayer in header file and initialise it in method you want.AvPlayer objects scope should be whole class playing video

Comment: yes its working on simulator , but it is not working on device , i have run the same code on device , it doesn't play it

Comment: Which device you run on?

Comment: What is happening exactly on device. Same as simulator??

Comment: on simulator of iPhone 8 plus , it works. which you shown up on your screen shot.on the device it shows up blank white screen.

Comment: Ok. But i can't test it on device as i don't have ios device. Sry for that